# Castle Windsor - Releasing Interceptor with Transient Lifestyle

Tags: castle-windsor, interceptor

It is stated in the [documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Interceptors&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) that you should always make interceptors transient. If I have this sample code;

```cs
//register interceptor
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sample.Interceptors")
.BasedOn<Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor>()
.LifestyleTransient());

//Configure components to intercept
 container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sample.Component")
.IncludeNonPublicTypes().InNamespace("Sample.Component", true)
            .Configure(c=>
                c.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<SampleInterceptor>())
                 .Anywhere.LifestyleSingleton())
                 .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                );
```

Should I worry about releasing `SampleInterceptor`, or will it be released automatically once the service in `Sample.Component` has been released by the container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your transient interceptor will have its lifespan bound to the object you associate it with, and will be released when that object gets released as any other part of that object's graph

Comment: I had a good feeling that this will be the behaviour of the transient interceptor, but it was not clearly described in the documentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to update the documentation to make it clearer :) It's an open wiki