# Lifestyle of Castle.Windsor interceptors

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, interceptor

In my [Webmethod]s I have code like this.

```
var something = container.ResolveSomething();
something.Run();
```

All registered components except one have lifestyle defined as PerWebRequest. One is registered as Singleton (logger).
For some of components I have defined and configured Interceptor that will log method calls and their results.

My question is: Will I have problems if I register this Interceptor with Lifestyle PerWebRequest? [Documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Interceptors&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) advices to make all Interceptors Transient and use other lifestyles if we are really sure we want to do it. If I register Interceptors with lifestyle Transient any of my about 100 methods will have to look like this.

```
IComponent component = null;
try
{
    component = container.ResolveComponent();
    compoment.Run();
}
finally
{
    container.Release(component);
}
```

So more boilerplate then real code.

Here is my interceptor:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public LoggingInterceptor(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var call = string.Format("{0}.{1}({2})", invocation.TargetType.FullName, invocation.Method.Name, string.Join(", ", invocation.Arguments.Select(arg => arg.ToString()).ToArray()));

        try
        {
            logger.Info(call);
            invocation.Proceed();

            logger.Info("Result: " + call + " = " + invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(call, e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I know WCF is better prepaired for IoC but I have to stay with ASP.NET WebServices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that even if the Interceptor is transient, it's lifetime is bound with intercepted component. It will be released with intercepted component because it is tracked by container.

Comment: That's true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356765/castle-windsor-releasing-interceptor-with-transient-lifestyle/11359033#11359033